# Could not index event to Elasticsearch Status=400, action=index, id=nil

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

`enter code here`This is what I am receiving on logstash running status:

[logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main][push to elasticsearch alerts index] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil Oct 09 12:42:43 ElasticSearch logstash[1064]: [2020-10-09T12:42:43,467][WARN ]

logstash pipeline:

- pipeline.id: main
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/*.conf"

  > logstash logfile:
  >
  > ```
  > [1000]/[1000] maximum shards open;"}}}}
  > [2020-10-09T15:28:35,200][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main][push to elasticsearch alerts
  > ```
  >
  > index] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400,
  > :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"wazuh-alerts-3.x-2020.10.09",
  > :routing=>nil, :_type=>"_doc"}, #LogStash::Event:0x544ae594],
  > :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"wazuh-alerts-3.x-2020.10.09",
  > "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>nil, "status"=>400,
  > "error"=>{"type"=>"validation_exception", "reason"=>"Validation
  > Failed: 1: this action would add [1] total shards, but this cluster
  > currently has [1000]/[1000] maximum shards open;"}}}}
  >
  > logstash conf file
  >
  > ```
  >         id => "push to elasticsearch alerts index"
  >         hosts => ["http://xxx.189.196.214:9200"]
  >         index => "wazuh-alerts-3.x-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  > #        ssl => true
  > #        cacert => "/etc/logstash/logstash.crt"
  > #        ssl_certificate_verification => false
  > #        user => "logstash_writer"
  > #        password => "pw"
  >       }
  >    }
  >    else {
  >       elasticsearch {
  >         id => "push to elasticsearch archives index"
  >         hosts => ["http://xxx.189.196.214:9200"]
  >         index => "wazuh-archives-3.x-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  > #        ssl => true
  > #        cacert => "/etc/logstash/logstash.crt"
  > #        ssl_certificate_verification => false
  > #        user => "logstash_writer"
  > #        password => ""
  >       }
  >    }
  > }
  >
  >  curl -XGET 206.189.196.214:9200/_cluster/stats?filter_path=indices.shards.total
  > {"indices":{"shards":{"total":1000}}}
  >
  > curl -XGET 206.189.196.214:9200/_cluster/alloca{
  >   "error" : {
  >     "root_cause" : [
  >       {
  >         "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
  >         "reason" : "unable to find any unassigned shards to explain [ClusterAllo
  >       }
  >     ],
  >     "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
  >     "reason" : "unable to find any unassigned shards to explain [ClusterAllocati
  >   },
  >   "status" : 400  curl -XGET 206.189.196.214:9200/ {   "name" : "node-1",   "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",   "cluster_uuid" :
  > ```
  >
  > "HgSWRRDZR76gW2a6NJjANg",   "version" : {
  > "number" : "7.9.2",
  > "build_flavor" : "default",
  > "build_type" : "deb",
  > "build_hash" : "d34da0ea4a966c4e49417f2da2f244e3e97b4e6e",
  > "build_date" : "2020-09-23T00:45:33.626720Z",
  > "build_snapshot" : false,
  > "lucene_version" : "8.6.2",
  > "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
  > "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"   },
  >
  > curl -XGET 'http://206.189.196.214:9200/_cluster/health?pretty' {
  > "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",   "status" : "green",   "timed_out"
  > : false,   "number_of_nodes" : 1,   "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  > "active_primary_shards" : 1000,   "active_shards" : 1000,
  > "relocating_shards" : 0,   "initializing_shards" : 0,
  > "unassigned_shards" : 0,   "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  > "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,   "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  > "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  > "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0

Comment: Hmmm, I'm afraid, you're going to have to tell us a little bit more about your context. Can you share your config and some more logging? Possibly with the `--debug` command-line switch

Comment: I am sorry...which Config file? for logstash or elasticsearch? Logging of what file...I am very new to this...but really wanting to learn it thru and thru.

Comment: Your Logstash pipeline configuration and the logging of logstash

Comment: This is not what I'm asking... also please update your question with technical details, it's not legible in comments.

Comment: There are a shard mistake on your cluster. Could you run this command : curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cluster/allocation/explain?pretty
I Guess, the main design/config of your cluster must be describe.

Comment: I have ran the command, see inside my question for what it returned? do I have a typo? I do not have localhost defined, so I have the real ip instead.

Comment: curl -v -GET '206.189.196.214:9200/_cat/indices?pretty this command shows all nodes in a "green state" ...there are lots of them. I have some dated back to 2019...wazuh alerts